# Cannot install Hadoop: InvalidAlgorithmParameter exception

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I downloaded the latest version of apache hadoop from the github repo and followed the steps here:

http://cleverowl.uk/2015/06/30/compiling-2-7-0-on-64-bit-linux/

I didn't install protobuf and java because I already have them installed on my machine. 
When installing with the command:

```
mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar
```

The following error appears:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/2.5.0/maven-bundle-plugin-2.5.0.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.5.0 @ 
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-main:3.0.2 (/home/andrew/hadoop-rel-release-3.0.2/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.5.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:pom:2.5.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

Any help?

Comment: That article is from 2015. You should look for instructions for the version you're installing.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/BUILDING.txt

Comment: Unless you are actually editing Hadoop source code, just download the binaries, not the sources

Comment: Solved by reinstalling the java ca certificates by apt. Thank you anyway.